# Why is having a password for your database important? (for example, in Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, passwords, web

My question is simple: How can a person access my database in production if he knows my password? I know that it can be done, because otherwise you wouldn't have to set a password for it, but I really want to know how.

Also, if someone knows the password for my database, can he execute all queries to my database (not only SELECT, but also the ones that alter the database)?

Comment: It is an example of defense in depth - when the server becomes comprimised, the database still has a measure of defense. Also, if you are on shared hosting with mulitiple databases on the same server, a password for the database is obviously a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database is on a server, a computer just like any other. It has a MAC address, probably a NIC, and most importantly, an IP address.

If you've ever used Window's remote connection utility, you are asked for the IP address of the computer, and the login credentials for the user's account. From there, you'd open the database management system (which is simply an *application* running on the computer), and once you've entered the database, it's just sitting there. Just like it does for you.

The process of deleting all of your hard work, for an attacker, includes the exact same steps you would take! Pick a good password, and don't store any sensitive information on any public-facing directories on the server!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to know :)

Answer (score 1):

> How can a person access my database in production if he knows my
>   password?

Through an exploit or other script where they can make a connection.

> if someone knows the password for my database, can he execute all
>   queries to my database (not only SELECT, but also the ones that alter
>   the database)

They can execute whatever that account has rights to.  This is a good reason that application logins only be given minimal rights.  Typically in full-featured database systems, you can give the application role/account only SELECT on certain tables or views (perhaps not even all columns), and generally modify data only through stored procedures.  By minimizing the surface area in this way, you have defense in depth, so not only is the account secured by a password, but the account has only a certain attack surface.  This is just one part of your overall security process.